# Creating a file using fopen()

Tags: c, file-handling, dev-c++, null-pointer

I am just creating a basic file handling program.
the code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
FILE *p;
p=fopen("D:\\TENLINES.TXT","r");
if(p==0)
{
    printf("Error",);

}

fclose(p);
}
```

This is giving Error, I cannot create files tried reinstalling the compiler and using different locations and names for files but no success.
I am using Windows 7 and compiler is Dev C++ version 5

Comment: Note: change `if(p==0)` to `if(p==NULL)`

Comment: `This is giving Error,`...please show us also...

Comment: It is always a good idea to RTFM in detail: http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.5.3

Comment: Just clarifying, the acronym as used here possibly means: _Read-The-Full-Manual_

Answer (score 10):

Change the *mode* argument in `fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode)`  from:

```
p=fopen("D:\\TENLINES.TXT","r");//this will not _create_ a file
if(p==0)                //  ^
```

To this:

```
p=fopen("D:\\TENLINES.TXT","w");//this will create a file for writing.
if(p==NULL)             //  ^   //If the file already exists, it will write over
                                //existing data.
```

If you want to *add* content to an existing file, you can use "a+" for the open mode.

[See fopen()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) (for more *open modes*, and additional information about the fopen family of functions)

Answer (score 2):

According to [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm), `fopen` returns NULL when error occurs. Therefore, you should check if `p` equals `NULL`.

Also, in `printf("Error",);`, omit the comma after string.

Comment: Using `0` to compare against is not nice, but valid. The reason why the file is not created is a different one.

Comment: Yes, that's why I used **should**.

Comment: So then your answer would have better suited as a comment, as it is not answering the question.

Comment: The `printf` part is not only a recommendation though, so I decided to include both parts in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should open the file in write mode.
Which creates the file . Read mode is only to read content 
or else you can use "r+" for both read and write.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open the file, but you need to make it first. Make a txt document with the name res.txt. It should be able to write your result into the text document.

```
<?php
  $result = $variable1 . $variable2 "=" .$res ."";

echo $result;

$myfile = fopen("res.txt", "a+") or die("nope");

fwrite($myfile, $result);

fclose($myfile)
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

fopen()
Syntax:

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen(“data.txt”,”r”);
if(fp!=NULL){
//file operations 
}
```

It is necessary to write FILE in the uppercase. The function fopen() will open a file “data.txt” 
in read mode.
The fopen() performs the following important task.

1. It searches the disk for opening the file.
2. In case the file exists, it loads the file from the disk into memory. If the file is found with huge contents then it loads the file part by part.
3. If the file does not exist this function returns a NULL. NULL is a macro defined character in the header file “stdio.h”. This  indicates  that  it  is  unable  to  open  file.  There  may  be following reasons for failure of fopen() functions.
   a.When the file is in protected or hidden mode.
   b.The file may be used by another program.
4. It locates a character pointer, which points the first cha
   racter of the file. Whenever a file is 
   opened the character pointer points to the first character of the file